# Copying files from S3 without downloading the directory which contains them

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to download all the text files within an S3 directory without downloading the directory which contains them:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/ . --recursive --exclude "*" --include "mydirectory*/*txt"
```

I would like to download all the text files contained in `mydirectory`.

Unfortunately I only know the first part of the name of this directory, and thus I have to use a wildcard for it, which means I can't attach it to the `mybucket` portion of the query.

This means that when I download the text files, they come inside `mydirectory`.  Is there a way to just download the text files, without downloading the directory which contains them as well?

Comment: you can write a small bash script which will first list contents of buckets; and then do aws s3 cp only on text files

Comment: @deepak no bash scripts, one liners only!!

Comment: What if there are two files: `mydirectory1/foo.txt` and `mydirectory2/foo.txt` -- that would cause the files to overwrite each other. How would you want to handle that?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, the first part of the file name is enough to uniquely identify it.  I know it sounds contrived but it's not.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS CLI alone cannot achieve what you wish, since it will recreate the directory structure for any nested directories.

You could write a shell command that first lists the files, then uses `aws s3 cp` to copy the individual files across with a different name, but the shell script shenanigans would be difficult to maintain.

Or, you could copy all the file *with their directories*, then use a `mv` command to move all the files back to a common directory, similar to:

- [command line - How can I move files by type recursively from a directory and its sub-directories to another directory? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/how-can-i-move-files-by-type-recursively-from-a-directory-and-its-sub-directorie)
- [command line - Move all files with a certain extension from multiple subdirectories into one directory - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67503/move-all-files-with-a-certain-extension-from-multiple-subdirectories-into-one-di)

(Yes, you don't care about extensions, but it's a similar concept.)

Or, if you want to do it in one command... write your own Python script to do it all for you!

Comment: yes using `mv` is my current solution, however bezos must be warned of this limitation, can you do this for me?